# Checking for a specific user

Tags: php

I have the following code which makes sure that the user is logged in. But I want to change to code to check for a specific user id. Can anyone help me with this?

```
function protect_page() {
    if (logged_in() === false) {
        header('Location: protected.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the function `logged_in` to be able to help you ;)

Comment: Or you can send back (using return;) the user ID in that "logged_in()" function and, check if user_id == what you want

Comment: Do you want to pass the specific user id to the function?

Comment: Yes, i want to only allow a user with id of 7 to be accessed to this specific page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your function `logged_in` and pass the specific user id to the function:

```
function logged_in($id) {
    //this function checks if the user is logged in and has a specific id
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id'] === $id) ? true : false;
}
```

You have to change your `protect_page` function to fit the new `logged_in` function:

```
function protect_page() {
    if (logged_in(7) === false){
        header('Location: protected.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could update your login function with an extra optional variable.
If you don't specify the $user_id variable it will take the value 0, which will only check if the user is logged in. If you do specify a certain $user_id then the function will return true if the user is logged in and the $user_id matches the id stored in the session.

```
function logged_in($user_id = 0) 
{
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && (($user_id == 0) || ($_SESSION['user_id'] == $user_id))) ? true : false;  //this function checks if the user is logged in and matches the given user identifier.
}
```